# Different focus behaviour between React Native 0.70.6 and 0.71.6 in a Fragment from Native Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native

I am using in React Native a native Android SDK which manages tap and pan within its fragment.
When using React Native 0.70.6 this work perfectly well in the RN application.
With React Native 0.71.6, it seems that the fragment does not get the focus.

Any idea what could be the reason and how to fix it ?
Being fairly new to RN, I am not sure how to investigate further.